# Install ansible 2.5 in Ubuntu server 22.04

Tags: 22.04, ansible

I'd like to install Ansible 2.5 in Ubuntu 22.04, because our deployment playbook incompatible with Ansible newer version. I tried installing from apt, but ppa doesn't provide 2.5 for 22.04. Installing by pip also not work as well. can someone shed some light on this please

Comment: The answer is self evident you need the correct version for the correct operating system.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you surely can manually install the 2.5 version of ansible for ubuntu 22.04.
The link : [https://launchpad.net/~ansible/+archive/ubuntu/ansible/+packages](https://launchpad.net/%7Eansible/+archive/ubuntu/ansible/+packages)

Use this to get specific package , unzip and use it run ansible.

Comment: I tried it, Ansible 2.5 depend on some python packages which is not support in Ubuntu 22.04